# Java encode image URL correctly

Tags: java, url, encode

I have a problem with the encoding of image URLs on my website and I tried 2 different encoding methods but they both have problems.
For example my image file has the following name: "Some special Characters;.jpg"

If I use `URLEncoder.encode(imageName, "UTF-8");` I get the following URL:

```
/some/url/Some+special+Characters%3B_92631.jpg
```

If I use `UrlEscapers.urlPathSegmentEscaper().escape(imageName)` I get:

```
/some/url/Some%20special%20Characters;_63414.jpg
```

I tried to find the correct URL of the image and I found this one:

```
/some/url/Some%20special%20Characters%3B_63414.jpg
```

It looks like URLEncoder is not encoding spaces correctly while URLEscapers does not encode the semicolon. Other special characters like ! or , work without any problems.

How can I encode my URL correctly?

Comment: `URLEncoder`, despite its name, is for encoding URL `arguments`, not URLs themselves. You need to look at `URI(String, String, String)` for this.

Comment: I founded an question look like what you asking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters let vote for me if it's works =))

Comment: @user207421 Interesting fact. My problem is URI seems not to allow spaces in the string so URI(imageName) does not work as it throws an Exception. Any idea?

Comment: @ThaoNguyen as I am not trying to encode parameters but the URL itself as user207421 mentioned so I don't think this solution will work for me. But thanks :)